# Oracle Apex Text box should show hyphen when null

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page item which is a text box and it has source as database cokumn.

Page item: P1_EMP_NAME

Database_Column : EMP_NAME

If it is null, in apex i want hyhen to display but currently it is coming as blank.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please mention default value as "-", If value is available in DB., it will show the actual value, else always it will display "-"

Answer (score 1):

The attribute "Value Placeholder" can be used for this.
[image]